# Tamanho de arquivo errado

Tags: php

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso consertar o seguinte erro: tenho o código abaixo, que dá o tamanho do arquivo, consultando dentro do diretório do host.

Contudo, digamos que o arquivo tenha 800Mbs, aí o que acontece é que ele mostra um valor um pouco mais abaixo, como 792Mbs, não seu valor exato. Gostaria de saber como posso consertar esse erro no código abaixo, desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

```
    <?php

    function tamanho_arquivo($arquivo) {
        $tamanhoarquivo = filesize($arquivo);

        /* Medidas */
        $medidas = array('KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');

        /* Se for menor que 1KB arredonda para 1KB */
        if($tamanhoarquivo < 999){
            $tamanhoarquivo = 1000;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $tamanhoarquivo > 999; $i++){
            $tamanhoarquivo /= 1024;
        }

        return round($tamanhoarquivo) . $medidas[$i - 1];
    }

// tamanho do arquivo 800Mbs
    echo tamanho_arquivo('filme.avi');

    ?>
```

**Atualização 18/05/2015:** Estou tendo um problema com esse código tipo eu tenho um dedicado e usei esta função para mostrar o tamanho do arquivo e adicionar o valor na SQL no meu dedicado funcionou só que no dedicado do meu amigo fica dando erro na linha 2 em **$tamanhoarquivo = filesize($arquivo);**

Fica dando o seguinte aviso **Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for ../driver/rar/documento1.rar in /home/meusite/public_html/adm/adicionador.php on line 49** a linha 49 no caso e onde esta essa função acima inicia e integra ao meu código de adicionamento de itens.

**Obs:** a linha 49 e **$tamanhoarquivo = filesize($arquivo);**

Alguém poderia me ajudar a concertar isso?

O **Bruno** já me ajudou a concertar o código para colocar o tamanho exato com tudo não estou intendendo o motivo de estar dando esse erro.

Comment: Como você obteve a informação do tamanho "real" do arquivo? Pode ser uma simples diferença entre o uso de kB e kb.

Comment: Está a dar um erro ou um aviso?

Comment: Normalmente esse erro/aviso pode acorrer devido a falta de permissões de leitura/escrita na directoria onde os ficheiros se encontram. Podes verificar quais são as permissões no ficheiro/directoria?

Comment: no caso e aviso o código não esta errado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) devolve o tamanho de um ficheiro em bytes, pelo que não deverias fazer

```
 $tamanhoarquivo /= 1024;
```

Mas sim

```
 $tamanhoarquivo /= 1000;
```

Uma nota importante do manual da função (pode não se aplicar no teu caso, uma vez que depende da arquitectura):

> Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use
>   32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected
>   results for files which are larger than 2GB.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda agora esta colocando o tamanho direito.